# Is it possible to pass class method instead of function and provide diffrent this pointer

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

class C{
private:
    int a;
public:
    C(int a):a(a){};
    int m(int b){
            return a + b;
    }
};
void f(int(*fp)(C*,int)){
    C c(20);
    std::cout << fp(&c, 5) << std::endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    C c(10);
    f(reinterpret_cast<int(*)(C*,int)>(c.m)); //has to be function pointer
    return 0;
}
```

This cast obviously doesn't work.

It can't be static method.

`f` needs to have this signature.

Comment: A better solution is through templates and lambdas. Why does it "has to be function pointer"? What is the original problem you're trying to solve? Why does `f` need to have that signature? What is your actual assignment? What requirements do you have? What limitations?

Comment: By the way, to get a pointer to a member function, static or not, you need to explicitly use the pointer-to operator `&` on the class function. Like `&C::m`.

Comment: _"`f` needs to have this signature."_ - Says who?

Comment: ```f``` is an api that expects callback but value from instance of  ```C``` is needed in the callback.

Comment: *What* API? Is it a C API? Does it have some kind of "user data pointer" you could set to the object you want to call the function on?

Comment: Given the constraints you provided, **no**, it is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to pass a pointer to a method, do it like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
private:
    int a;
public:
    C(int a) : a(a) {}
    int add(int b) { return a + b; }
    int sub(int b) { return a - b; }
};

void f(int (C::*fp)(int)) {
    C c(20);
    std::cout << (c.*fp)(5) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(&C::add);
    f(&C::sub);
}
```

The above example still uses a `C` instance hard-coded in the function `f`. If you want to call the method on different instances of `C`, then you should instead pass a reference (or pointer) to the object:

```
void f(C &c, int (C::*fp)(int)) {
    std::cout << (c.*fp)(5) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    C foo(10), bar(20);
    f(foo, &C::add);
    f(foo, &C::sub);
    f(bar, &C::add);
    f(bar, &C::sub);
}
```

Regarding this:

> ```
> void f(int(*fp)(C*,int))
> ```
>
> f needs to have this signature.

Well, you can sort-of do this if you write adapter functions with the signature `int (*fp)(C*, int)`. You still need to get the `C*` value from somewhere. It cannot be implicit. So, going back to your original example that hard-codes `C(20)` in the function `f`:

```
#include <iostream>

class C {
private:
    int a;
public:
    C(int a) : a(a) {}
    int add(int b) { return a + b; }
    int sub(int b) { return a - b; }
};

// Adapters with the appropriate signature
int add(C* c, int b) { return c->add(b); }
int sub(C* c, int b) { return c->sub(b); }

void f(int (*fp)(C*, int)) {
    C c(20);
    std::cout << fp(&c, 5) << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    f(add);
    f(sub);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Old school C-style function pointers aren't the C++ way to pass functions. If you're still working with C libraries, you're stuck, but if you control the code used, there are better ways.

This is a cut & paste from some of my code:

```
#include <functional>
...

typedef std::function<void(HTTPServerRequest &, HTTPServerResponse &)> Callback;
```

By using `std::function` you are enabling the use of non-static class methods or lambdas. I tend to prefer lambdas, because otherwise you also have to use std::bind, and I think that's ugly.

So if I can do this to define a `Route` constructor.

```
Route(const std::string &m, const std::string &p, const std::string &d, Route::Callback );
```

And I can pass that callback argument as:

```
[=](HTTPServerRequest &request, HTTPServerResponse &response) {
    handleRequest(request, response);
}
```

(That's a lambda.) If I'm using this from some class, and handleRequest is a non-static method in that class, this works, and it's pretty clean.

You can also pass in C-style function pointers or use `std::bind()`.